# How to access data field of a JSON request send by Flex client in JAX-RS

Tags: json, apache-flex, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I have the following JAX-RS service.

```
@Path("config")
public class ConfigurationResponder {

    @GET
    @Produces({"application/json"})
    @Consumes({"application/json"})
    public SomeResponse handleMessage() {

        SomeResponse response = new SomeResponse();
        // calculations...
        return response;
    }
}
```

I build some request in a Flex client.

```
var message:Object = {};
message.type = "get_configuration";
message.data = "some data";

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(fullUrl);
request.contentRype = "application/json";
request.data = message;
request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;

var loader:URLLoader = ...
loader.load(request);
```

The JAX-RS service receives the request and respond successfully with some dummy response, but I have no access to the `request.data` field.

How do I access the data of the request message (which is `{"type":"get_configuration","data":"some data"}` in this particular example)? I think that I'm supposed to add some parameters to the `handleMessage` method like

```
public SomeResponse handleMessage(Object message) {...
```

but this does not work at all. The request got 415 response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`@QueryParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html) to register the query parameter as method argument.

```
public SomeResponse handleMessage(@QueryParam("query") String data) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: 10x. About the reason why it is 'query', instead of 'data' - I really don't know, I suppose that I used Flex URLRequest class in not the proper way.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry, can't help more on Flex part, I've never used it.